# Need help in google map on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, javascript, google-maps

I have a google map on my asp.net page. on which its showing image(marker) on cityname .
please tell me how can i fire event onclick on that marker.

Answer (score 0):

GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(point) {
           this.openInfoWindowHtml("" + this.value + "");});
          return marker;
    }